# Difference between the the percentage and the absolute count of a variable

Tags: r

I have a variable which is the outcome in the model that I'm fitting and when I fit the model once with the percentage of this variable I get significant results, but when I use the absolute account for this variable in the model the significant p value become less. so my question is what is the difference between using the absolute count of a variable and the percentage of it when we fit a linear regression model? can you help me please? My analysis is ANCOVA and this is the example

```
fit<-lm(count of the outcome variable~ SEX+RACE+GENE)
#count here are numbers ranging from (-12,2000)
fit<-lm(Percentage of the outcome variable~ SEX+RACE+GENE)
#percentage here are ranging from (-1,50)
```